Freestanding tub installation method
I am upgrading bathroom and got jaccuzi freestanding oval bathtub. I don't have access for underneath so trying to find best way to get it installed.
Option 1. Manual is saying to just use  fpt to slip adapter and connect to p trap tube using cement.
Option 2. I saw tub rough in. They seems to be $150 and I think it will enable me to remove and reinstall the tube if needed? Not sure if installation is easier/better?
Option 3: flexible low profile p trap. Seems to be easy/lazy way but not sure about durability
Which one would you recommend?
